# Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 20 and input n_features is 4

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, sklearn-pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmBat.png)I am getting this error while I'm using random forest classifier. Here is my code:

```
import quandl, math    
import numpy as np    
import pandas as pd    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
from matplotlib import style   
import datetime    
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier    
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder    
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

train = pd.read_csv("train.csv", index_col=None)    
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=1)    
X1 = vectorizer.fit_transform(train['question'])    
X=X1.toarray()    
corpus=['tell me your name']    
t1= vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)    
t=t1.toarray()    
number=LabelEncoder()   
train['answer']=number.fit_transform(train['answer'].astype('str'))    
features = ['question','answer']    
y= train['question'].values    
clf=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=20)    
clf.fit(X,y)    
predicted_result=clf.predict(t)
```

Comment: Why are you supplying train['question'] to both X and y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same trained vectorizer for both train and test data. In the second time if you again fit the data then it will turn it into a vector based on only this new data.

```
X1 = vectorizer.fit_transform(train['question'])
t1= vectorizer.transform(corpus)
```

Comment: i took testing data from another file and i tried vectorizer for it.its working!

Comment: now i would like to know my output is coming as integer because i converted string to integer at training time but i want string as a output.give me suggestion

Comment: I didnt get you. If you want string then thats what input is. Vectorizer means converting your string ip to vectoe of integeres

Comment: @KapilSen You want `predicted_result` to be string? Then you should have supplied it as such in `y`.No need to encode it. Most scikit estimators support strings in y (Not X).

Comment: @rakesh i want to be string as output.fine my problem solved.